# Casting jsonb field's value as datetime field and then querying on it throws error

Tags: python, django, django-models, jsonb

I have a model with jsonb field containing datetime value

`{'datetime': '2021-10-18 12:37:00.000Z'}`

but when I cast it using

`annotate(datetime=Cast('jsonb__datetime', output_field=models.DateTimeField()))`

it throws the error
`'DateTimeField' object has no attribute 'model'`

The model looks like this

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    jsonb = models.JsonField(default=dict)
```

I am using
Python 3.10
Django 3.2.8

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to achieve here? What is it that you're trying to cast?

Comment: I am trying to query datetime value stored inside jsonb field in django model so for that I am casting that value using 
`annotate(datetime=Cast('jsonb__datetime, output_field=models.DateTimeField()))` but when I do filter on for e.g `Ticket.objects.filter(datetime__gt=datetime.now())` it throws error `'DateTimeField' object has no attribute 'model'`